# Getting both a string and JAXB object from a Jersey request

Tags: java, jaxb, jersey

I'm looking to do exactly what the question below discusses (ie. get back BOTH the string and JAXB object in a Jersey request for logging purposes).

[JAX-RS get entity as JAXB object and as String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828526/jax-rs-get-entity-as-jaxb-object-and-as-string)

Since this question is 2.5 years old at this point I was wondering if there's now an easier way to do this than adding in that extra MessageBodyReader code into every request class. This would be a time consuming and costly retrofit to do at this point for our API code base. It would surprise me if there were no easy way to do this given how long JAXB/Jersey have been around and how common this problem must be, but I can't find any information on it other than that old post.